# Multiple LEFT JOIN (MS Access+VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, left-join

I'm stuck in a query.

**Tables:**

In the 'favourites' table are stored favourite articles (products).

in the "articles" table are stored all products avalaible.

in the "providers" table are stored all providers of these products. The relation between products and providers are stored in "artPRov" table.

In the table "invoices" are stored purchases.

**RELATIONS**

[image: RELATIONS]

**QUERY**

> select favourites.*,articles.article,artProv.LastCost, invoice.idInv,
>   providers.name
>       FROM ((((favourites LEFT JOIN articles ON favourites.idArt=articles.idArt) LEFT JOIN providers ON
>   favourites.idProv=providers.idProv) LEFT JOIN artProv ON
>   favourites.idArt=artProv.idArt AND artProv.idProv=providers.idProv)
>   LEFT JOIN invoices ON favourites.idInv=invoices.idInv)

**join error:**

```
> LEFT JOIN artProv ON favourites.idArt=artProv.idArt AND
> artProv.idProv=providers.idProv
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  I don't see an error in your syntax. So I don't understand what is wrong and what you would prefer as a better outcome.  If you could be more clear about that, I think you would get a solution.

Comment: Was `LFET JOIN providers ON favourites.idProv=providers.idProv` a typing error here on SO?  Access is annoying with requiring the parenthesis around joins -- di you create the joins in the designer to check that part of the syntax?  Note, you can _edit_ your own post to fix the LFET if that is not the problem.

Comment: @tgolisch: if I execute this query from Access, show a message box with this error: "JOIN expression is not suported". I want to display all articles stored in "favourites" table. If these articles have invoices ("invoice" table) and providers ("providers" table) linked, I want to display too.

Comment: @phaedra: sorry, updated post.

Comment: Did you try to add another left join from `artProv to providers`?

Comment: @murder where? if I add after get the same error "JOIN expression is not suported". SELECT favourites.*,articles.article,artProv.LastCost, invoice.idInv, providers.name FROM ((((favourites LEFT JOIN articles ON favourites.idArt=articles.idArt) LEFT JOIN providers ON favourites.idProv=providers.idProv) LEFT JOIN artProv ON favourites.idArt=artProv.idArt) LEFT JOIN providers ON  artProv.idProv=providers.idProv) LEFT JOIN invoices ON favourites.idInv=invoices.idInv)

Comment: I added a screenshot with relations

Comment: If you add the other left join you need another `(`) in front of your `FROM`

Comment: I added. But the same error is shown "JOIN expression is not supported"